# Possible to send automated email?

Tags: ios

The iOS SDK class `MFMailComposeViewController` can be used to let the user compose an email message.

What I'd like to do, is for the iOS app to send an email in the background, with no user interaction. Is this at all possible/allowed in the iOS SDK?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nope. There isn't any API available to do this. You'd need to roll your own SMTP client and have the user enter credentials into your application. On top of that Apple may not approve this.

Comment: In order to setup your own SMTP client you can use a library like MailCore https://github.com/MailCore/MailCore

Comment: look this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8274538/send-email-without-gui/45283096#45283096

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, I don't think Apple would ever allow this because (for example) then you could just get everyone's email address by auto-sending mail to yourself.  :(

Answer (score 2):

I actually wanted to implement something like this for the express purpose of alerting me when a critical error happens on an app in the app market.

Best solution would be to create an API (just ping a php file or something), and have it send the relative alert message to your email).