# Can I post to a user's wall from iOS app without connecting the app to Facebook?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-sharer

I would like to post to user's wall: a link + short message from user. Can I do it **without connecting my iOS app to Facebook** (by passing data to Facebook app or any other way but not through the browser)?

Note: user will submit the post, all I want is not having to connect my app to Facebook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always post by email (see: https://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=210153612350847) but you'd have to ask the user to enter the address in your app.
And check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10185756/send-email-in-background-from-ios) without presenting the email form to the user .