# Share a link to mail using DropBox API

Tags: ios, objective-c, dropbox, dropbox-api

My requirement is to upload a picture taken in my iOS device to dropbox and then share the link to that picture to a given mail address.

Using the `DBRestClient` delegate methods I am able to get the link for the uploaded file.

Now,I want to send this link to a mail and I want this to happen in Dropbox itself so that I don't have to use `MFMailViewController`

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Why don't you want to use `MFMailViewController`? You don't want your user to know that you're piping these e-mails off? You don't want your user to control what the e-mail says/looks like at all?

Comment: its just an image and the user will be sending it to the same mail he opted for.so i thought it will be better like this so that the user won't be forced to review the same thing again and again.

Comment: In that case, you'll probably be better off doing this on a server backend.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Dropbox-API isn't supporting this feature (yet).

You can try sending your mail via a smtp server, if you really want to avoid user interaction. An example how to do this is available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10185756/send-email-in-background-from-ios).